# Using CSS to Secure/Blur Out Names

Tags: css

I work for a school district and occasionally have to give web site demos that include student and/or teacher names. It's a big no-no to display names in any sort of public fashion, so I've developed a css class that will blur out the names. It works great but I'm wanting to make sure I have it as secure as possible. Currently the only 'hole' in it is if somebody were to actually highlight the name, it shows up.  Is there a way to include highlighting -- and anything else I may be missing -- into the class to help with security?

```css
/*Use these classes to blur sensitive data from appearing during demos*/

.secBlur,
a.secBlur:hover,
a.secBlur:focus {
  /*color: transparent;*/
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="secBlur">Jimmy G.</td>
      <td>Software Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="secBlur">Dave G.</td>
      <td>Foo Fighter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're actually sending the name to the browser, the information is there to read for anyone who cares to look hard enough. If you truly want to hide those names, you must not send them from the server to the browser in the first place.

Comment: Anything done with CSS alone is pointless as the plain text version is readily available in the page source

Comment: Yeah I thought about that..it's a secure website -- you have to have a login to access this level of data. I have other precautions in place so that principals can only see students at their schools, teachers can only see students on their roster -- all filtered at the database level. This is just being done so that if I or somebody else needs to present, there's no way to accidentally display the names during the presentation. Thanks for considering all aspects of my issue though!! Greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `user-select`

```css
/*Use these classes to blur sensitive data from appearing during demos*/

.secBlur,
a.secBlur:hover,
a.secBlur:focus {
  /*color: transparent;*/
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */ 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="secBlur">Jimmy G.</td>
      <td>Software Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="secBlur">Dave G.</td>
      <td>Foo Fighter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The names will still be available in plain text in the page source.

Comment: yes, it just answer for how to disable text highlighting